# Querying a mongo DB collection into a struct

Tags: go, mgo

Defining this struct

```
type SymbolMCAddrPort struct {
        ID        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        Symbol    string
        MCAddr    string
        MCPort    int
}

session, err := mgo.Dial("10.0.0.61")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer session.Close()

csap := session.DB("FX").C("MCAddrPortPairs")
```

If I say

```
var resultsSMP bson.M
err = csap.Find(bson.M{"Symbol": "EUR/USD"}).One(&resultsSMP)
fmt.Println(resultsSMP)
```

I correctly see

```
map[_id:ObjectIdHex("56fc34e961fed32064e656b0") Symbol:EUR/USD MCAddr:239.0.0.222 MCPort:345]
```

But if I say

```
resultsSMP := SymbolMCAddrPort{}
err = csap.Find(bson.M{"Symbol": "EUR/USD"}).One(&resultsSMP)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(resultsSMP)
```

I just see

```
{ObjectIdHex("56fc34e961fed32064e656b0")   0}
```

I note that the ID is correct, but I can't get the rest of the fields in the struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tags](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag) to hint [Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Unmarshal) what the key names for each field are.

```
type SymbolMCAddrPort struct {
   ID        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
   Symbol    string `bson:"Symbol"`
   MCAddr    string `bson:"MCAddr"`
   MCPort    int `bson:"MCPort"`
}
```

From documentation of [Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Unmarshal),

> The lowercased field name is used as the key for each exported field,
>   but this behavior may be changed using the respective field tag.

So by default, when you are using a struct, it expects keys to be lowercased values of field names. When the key name should be anything else field tags have to be used to specify the key name.